# authlogic and oauth-plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, authlogic

does somebody tested - will authlogic works with oauth-plugin (https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.  I am currently integrating **oauth-plugin**'s service providership with my own auth system (which predates **authlogic**, **acts_as_authenticated** and all the rest).

**oauth-plugin** service providership works by means of a code generator generating two controllers, which are then tied into some library files in the plugin.  All of these files expect a `login_required` class method with the same semantics that **acts_as_authenticated** uses.

**authlogic** makes no assumptions about your controllers at all, so it won't work out of the box with **oauth-plugin**, however that design decision also means it will be fairly easy to structure your controllers in the expected way.  Therefore it should be (maybe trivially) easy to build a shim to support **oauth-plugin**.

However in my case I've decided to run the generator then to extract what I need from the plugin and delete the plugin itself.  The primary reason I am doing this is that I explicitly don't have the `login_required` method in my auth system, so I would have to monkey patch the lib to get it to work.  Secondly, there's a lot of stuff in the plugin I just don't need.  Thirdly, most of the stuff that is truly library-level has already been abstracted into the **oauth** gem proper, so the stuff living in the **oauth-plugin** lib directory is in this weird no mans land between the generated code and the actual library.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process of getting this to work right now.  I just rolled my own using the authlogic methods to make it play nicely.  (I'm trying to get a provider working, so the authlogic-oauth doesn't seem right for me)

I'll edit as I go

```
def logged_in?
  return true if current_user 
end 

def login_required 
  return true if logged_in? 
  store_location 
  redirect_to new_user_session_path and return false                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Authlogic has an add-on that was specifically developed for it, which can be found [here](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth/tree/master).

Comment: i need plugin to make oauth server, but not to allow users to login using credentials from third party site thru oauth protocol

Comment: oauth-plugin by pelle works great with restful-authentication, but i'd like to know - will it works with authlogic or not

Comment: huh .. i need to make authlogic-enabled site as provider, but not consumer