# Error while implementing oauth provider using oauth-plugin(pelle)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to secure my web application's API using oauth. I searched a lot & finally decided to try following link http://stakeventures.com/articles/2007/11/26/how-to-turn-your-rails-site-into-an-oauth-provider.
I followed the steps & I am able to register new application successfully.
I am using devise for authentication & the pelle's oauth-plugin is compatible with **acts_as_authenticated, restful_authentication or restful_openid_authentication** as mentioned in the above post.
So I am getting following error when I try to run http://localhost:3000/oauth/autherize

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `login_required' for #<OauthController:0xc410490>):
```

I searched for the solution & I got following link http://groups.google.com/group/oauth-ruby/browse_thread/thread/3656e3904050fd9a.

Now is there any alternate solution other than mentioned in above link. If yes then please guide me about that & if not then please tell me how to actually implement the solution.
Where actually the oauth_controller_spec.rb file resides? Do I need to fork & edit the plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look here: [authlogic and oauth-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205763/authlogic-and-oauth-plugin). Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072703/498575) is helpful.